# undefined method `send_bill' for BillMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm generating bills for my application and delivering it via email for customers.
When I create a new bill it send the email but, throws the following error:

```
undefined method `send_bill' for BillMailer:Class
app/models/bill_observer.rb:5:in `after_create'
```

So, I've run the BillMailer.send_bill from rails consle and it worked fine.

This is driving me crazy, because it sends the email, but throws an error.

Any thought about what it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, after talk with some other rails developers, I discovered that the Threads was messing up my code I was doing something like that

```
Thread.new do
  #code
end
```

When I removed the Threads it works without strange errors